# Sharepoint clientContext currentUser in CAML query

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, caml

I am currently using a combination of things in order to get the current user in SharePoint 2013 so that I can automatically query my data set for the logged in user.

I am encountering a strange error where if I do not use an alert box in my retrieveListItems function, I get SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_$y_0'. If I put a simple alert('Hi'); at the beginning of this function, I do not get the error and my charts render correctly for the user.

Below is my (sloppy) code, but if anyone can offer any insight as to why it may be doing this and how I can make sure that error is resolved without having to use any alert boxes, I would be very appreciative.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,"sp.js");

var currentUser;


function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate (this,this.retrieveUser), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed2));
}

function onQueryFailed2(){
    alert('2');
}

function retrieveUser(){
    currentUser = currentUser.get_title();
    //alert(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,this.retrieveListItems),
        Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed2)
    )
}

    //retrieve list data from above sharepoint site based on List Name

function retrieveListItems() {

    clientContext.load(currentUser, 'Title');
    //alert('Rendering...');
    //var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);  

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('APS Portfolio');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
    //currentUser = 'Fox, Natalie G';
    //clientContext.load(currentUser);                  
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AIT_x0020_App_x0020_Manager'/><Value Type='Text'>" +currentUser+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");   
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}
```

I am new to using the clientContext functionality, but am very interested in learning more about it and what I can do to solve this error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why the first line of retrieveListItems() is:

```
clientContext.load(currentUser, 'Title');
```

Anyway, this library simplifies your code a lot so I would recommend this:
https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/

The code would be something like:

```
$SP().list("My List").get({
  fields:"Title",//whatever fields you want
  where:"Author = '[Me]'"//[Me] is the current user that is logged in
}).then(function(row) {
  console.log(row[0].getAttribute("Title"));
});
```

With regards to an explanation for the issue, I suspect it is to do with async, i.e. a variable is being used before it has been assigned relevant value by a previous function.